# How to return records when there are no relations on a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `Records` that can have `zero_to_many` `RecordLabels`.
I need to get records that don't have labels created by a specific user and there are fewer labels than `required_label_count` altogether.

The query below works only if there is at least one `RecordLabel`.

How can I get a `Record` if it doesn't have any `RecordLabels` or when it does it should satisfy the conditions?

```
Record.for_company(company_id)
    .joins(:record_labels)
    .group('records.id')
    .having('count(record_labels.id) <= ?', required_label_count)
    .where('record_labels.user_id != ?', user_id)
```

Comment: Depending on your rails version you can use `left_joins(:record_labels)` instead of `joins`. In older versions you would have to use `joins` with a String specifying the left join or use an `Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin`; however you will need to change the where clause as well so that `user_id` can be `NULL` otherwise the result will still be an inner join.

Comment: Ah!  That `user_id` null check was what tripped me up! Thank you!